# Not able to deploy Angular7 app on github pages

Tags: angular, github-pages

Github Repo:- UI-asset-Agm.

ProjectName:- UI-assets
I am running the following commands to deploy angular app on github pages

```
ng build --prod --base-href "https://skatia.github.io/UI-asset-Agm"



   ngh or 
     npx ngh --dir=dist/UI-assets
```

But when I go to

```
 https://skatia.github.io/UI-asset-Agm/ or 
https://skatia.github.io/UI-assets/
```

it says site not found

dist/UI-assets/index.html is

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>UIAssets</title>
  <base href="https://skatia.github.io/UI-asset-Agm">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/tachyons@4/css/tachyons.min.css">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.491137759dd7a3a3a7e2.css"></head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.ec2944dd8b20ec099bf3.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.1ef83d22ada557f4a131.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.ca0a7471bf0fe9d8f66d.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have got an empty git repository named **ui-asset-agm** for your github account named **skatia**, and a working Angular 6+ project (`ng build --prod` runs without errors) the following should work for you.

---

**Setting up Angular**

In your **angular.json** add (or update) the following rules to your `configurations/production` entry

```
"production": {
  ...
  "baseHref": "/"
  "deployUrl": "https://skatia.github.io/ui-asset-agm"
}
```

also change the `outputPath` in the same file to `docs` (it is `dist` by default). Build with

```
ng build --prod
```

After doing so there should be a folder called `/docs` with your successfully built angular application. If not, there are some issues with your Angular project.

---

**Pushing to github**

Add your github repository as remote

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/skatia/ui-asset-agm
```

and push it to github with

```
git push -u origin master
```

In github go to the repos settings and select something like *"use github pages with master/docs folder"*. Your page will then be available under

```
https://skatia.github.io/ui-asset-agm
```

It takes some time for the site to be published, in my experience approximately one or two minute(s).

Comment: After ng build --prod, what I need to do? Push to github? I didnt understand....., 

No ngh command?

Comment: I made changes in angular.json . then ng build --prod then ngh but it didn't make any effect

Comment: If it is run `git push origin master` otherwise run `git remote add origin https://github.com/skatia/ui-asset-agm` and `git push -u origin master`.

Comment: I don't think. Is there any check?

Comment: `git remote get-url origin`

Comment: above command gave me following url https://git.rbfcu.org/skatia/UI-asset-Agm.git

Comment: I am getting following error ....................

index.html could not be copied to 404.html. Continuing without an error.
(Hint: are you sure that you have setup the --dir parameter correctly?)
{ Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'D:\stylesGuide\UI-assets_bkp\dist\index.html'
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'lstat',
  path: 'D:\\stylesGuide\\UI-assets_bkp\\dist\\index.html' }

Comment: run `git remote set-url https://github.com/skatia/ui-asset-agm` and `git push -u origin master`. Make sure you have an existing empty Github project named "ui-asset-agm"